# Found: nvarchar2, expected: varchar2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have spring boot application with this configuration:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl_auto =  validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

I also tried other naming strategies, but in this case they works same.
I want validate, but not checking for data types  varchar2,nvarchar2 
I know one solution

```
columnDefinition = "nvarchar2"
```

but I don't want write so, I need some config to avoid this.